# ITextSharp - Remove textbox border programmatically

Tags: c#, itext

How can I remove the textbox border programmatically with itextsharp using C#?

Comment: Are we talking about a form field or some text with a box drawn around it?  An existing PDF or one you're generating?

Answer (score 0):

Is the textbox actually a table? If so the PdfPCell Border property seems the way to go

Comment: No, I think not. Is a form field.